# what is the default value for kafka.concurrency in ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

What is the default value for **private Integer concurrency;**  , in ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java ?

Kafka version : 0.10.2.1
spring-kafka version : 1.0.5-RELEASE

Answer (score 5):

one.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java#L59

```
private int concurrency = 1;
```

> 1.0.5-RELEASE

All 1.x users are encouraged to upgrade to at least 1.3.5 because it has a much simpler threading model, thanks to KIP-62. The current release is 2.1.7; all those versions are compatible with the 10.2 broker, see [the project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) for a compatibility matrix.